# How would I get the Column Chart to combine the same [DEST #] and give me the average

Tags: excel, excel-2010

So I am trying to get the Column Chart to get the average percentage of [DEST #] that are the same, so they do not add extra columns of multiple [DEST #]. Instead the Chart will automatically give the average percentage of the multiple [DEST#] into a single column. Pic 2 is the goal.

[Chart with multiple DEST #](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WljcS.png)

[Goal Chart that has 1 column per DEST# that gives the average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Quxa.png)